# make library use jpa annotations without depends on any implementation

Tags: java, maven, jpa, maven-3

I'm building a library where I scan a class and check if their field as `OneToMany` and `ManyToOne` annotations. I currently added eclipselink 3.6 as dependecy of my module, like this

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
  <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
  <version>2.6.0</version>
</dependency>
```

but I don't want to make my lib dependent on eclipselink, I want it able to be used with any JPA implementation. How do i do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, there's no standard package that provides only the annotations/interface (like, for example, on the servlet spec). Each ORM has their own package, but they **all** follow the jpa standard. What you can do is declare the dependency as `optional`.

For Eclipselink

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.persistence</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.0</version>
    <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>
```

Probably you'll need to depend on eclipselink for your tests, so you can mark the original dependency only for test...

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
  <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
  <version>2.6.0</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```